# Can someone explain what is happening in the pic and why my node is loading with dB 4.8.30 pl from top to bottom?

Tags: bitcoin-core, logging

```
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z Using wallet directory C:\Bitcoin\wallets\wallets\*****""
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)…
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z Using wallet C:\Bitcoin\wallets\wallets\****** wallet\wallet.dat
2023-04-12T14:00:45Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open:
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core is starting up, that's all.

It's reporting that it is using a version of the database software that was written/released in April 2010. It has nothing to do with your own wallet, just with the software in use.

Comment: Thanks Pieter hope your well,So this is displayed on everyone's log when starting bitcoin core also the worker threads are they just part of software aswel?

Comment: Yes, this is just the normal startup procedure.